# Looking for a sample CSV file to upload product list on V 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, csv, upload, sample

Looking for a sample CSV file to upload product list on Magento 1.9 please help

Comment: If you have any products currently in the store you can go to System -> Import/Export -> Dataflow – Profiles -> Export All Products and export a file. This should show you the required csv structure and the data for the products. If you don't just create a test one first and then export.

Answer (score 3):

Please find sample csv product file from below links

**1)** https://emagicone.com/file_examples/Magento/magento_import_admin_sample_file.csv(`Reference:` https://www.mag-manager.com/useful-articles/tipstricks/required-csv-file-values-for-error-free-magento-import-via-admin/)

**2)** https://github.com/firebearstudio/magento2-import-export-sample-files

Comment: Why you add M2 example while he is asking M 1.9?